AWS Amplify Gen 2 REST API with Lambda and DynamoDB
I am using AWS Amplify Hosting (Gen 2) and have created a REST API backed by Lambda. The Lambda function is supposed to send an email (which works fine) and save the submitted data to a DynamoDB table. However, when trying to save data, I get the following error:

ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found

I have verified that the table name is correct and tested using the specific table ARN. Additionally, I tried using a wildcard for table names to ensure broader access permissions.
This is my API Stack.
// create a new API stack
const apiStack = backend.createStack("api-stack");

// create a new REST API
const myRestApi = new RestApi(apiStack, "RestApi", {
  restApiName: "myRestApi",
  deploy: true,
  deployOptions: {
    stageName: "dev",
  },
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
    allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS, // Restrict this to domains you trust
    allowMethods: Cors.ALL_METHODS, // Specify only the methods you need to allow
    allowHeaders: Cors.DEFAULT_HEADERS, // Specify only the headers you need to allow
  },
});

backend.ApiContactFormFunction.resources.lambda.addToRolePolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    actions: ['ses:SendEmail', 'ses:SendRawEmail'],
    resources: ['*']
  }),
)

backend.ApiContactFormFunction.resources.lambda.addToRolePolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    effect: Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: [
      'dynamodb:PutItem',
    ],
    resources: [
      "*"
    ]
  })
)

// create a new Lambda integration
const lambdaIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(
  backend.ApiContactFormFunction.resources.lambda
);

// create a new resource path with IAM authorization
const itemsPath = myRestApi.root.addResource("contact-form", {
  defaultMethodOptions: {
    authorizationType: AuthorizationType.NONE,
  },
});

// add methods you would like to create to the resource path
itemsPath.addMethod("GET", lambdaIntegration);
itemsPath.addMethod("POST", lambdaIntegration);
itemsPath.addMethod("DELETE", lambdaIntegration);
itemsPath.addMethod("PUT", lambdaIntegration);

// add a proxy resource path to the API
itemsPath.addProxy({
  anyMethod: true,
  defaultIntegration: lambdaIntegration,
});

// create a new IAM policy to allow Invoke access to the API
const apiRestPolicy = new Policy(apiStack, "RestApiPolicy", {
  statements: [
    new PolicyStatement({
      actions: ["execute-api:Invoke"],
      resources: [
        `${myRestApi.arnForExecuteApi("*", "/contact-form", "dev")}`,
      ],
    }),
  ],
});

// attach the policy to the authenticated and unauthenticated IAM roles
backend.auth.resources.authenticatedUserIamRole.attachInlinePolicy(
  apiRestPolicy
);
backend.auth.resources.unauthenticatedUserIamRole.attachInlinePolicy(
  apiRestPolicy
);

// add outputs to the configuration file
backend.addOutput({
  custom: {
    API: {
      [myRestApi.restApiName]: {
        endpoint: myRestApi.url,
        region: Stack.of(myRestApi).region,
        apiName: myRestApi.restApiName,
      },
    },
  },
});

This is my lambda function:
import type { APIGatewayProxyHandler, APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 } from "aws-lambda";
import { DynamoDBClient, PutItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';

const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: 'eu-west-1' });

const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: 'af-south-1' });

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event) => {
  console.log("event", event);

  const body = JSON.parse(event.body || '{}');
  const { fullName, email, phoneNumber, message } = body;

const recipient = 'test@gmail.com';
  const subject = `Contact Form - ${fullName}`;

  const htmlTemplate = `Email Body`;

  const command = new SendEmailCommand({
    Source: 'test@gmail.com',
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [recipient]
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: { Data: htmlTemplate }
      },
      Subject: { Data: subject }
    }
  });

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Restrict this to domains you trust
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", // Specify only the headers you need to allow
    },
    body: '',
  };

  try {
    const result = await sesClient.send(command);
    console.log(`Email sent to ${recipient}: ${result.MessageId}`);

    const tbCommand = new PutItemCommand({
      TableName: 'Table',
      Item: {
        email: { S: 'Test email' },
        message: { S: 'Test message' },
        phone: { S: 'Test phone' },
        fullName: { S: 'Fullname' }
      },
    });

    await ddbClient.send(tbCommand);

    response.body = JSON.stringify(`Email have been send to ${fullName} - ${email}}!`)
    
  } catch (error) {
    response.statusCode = 500;
    response.body = JSON.stringify(`There was an error sending the email: ${error}`)
  }

  return response;
};

Any help would be appreciated.

Can you share the output of calling describe-table using the CLI or SDK languages of your choice?

Hi so I still get ResourceNotFoundExceprion. I have created the table using Amplify Gen 2 Schema, would this make a difference?

You're not using the correct table name. Use list-tables to see what tables amplify has created.

I accidentally used the wrong table name in my project. Is there a way to reference the Amplify-generated table name dynamically, instead of hardcoding it and including the random ID?

Make sure you use the correct table name in the following form:
The table name is in the form [Name]-[AppSyncApiId]-[env]
Then you can resolve it similar to this, depending on how you build your infra:
"Fn::ImportValue": {
  "Fn::Sub": "${AppSyncApiId}:GetAtt:CoursesTable:Name"
}

